# Is is possible to tint the TabBar without tinting the icons?

Tags: ios

My app designers want a silver tab bar, which I've implemented by setting the tint color, and this works fine:

[image]

But this is also tinting the tab bar icons in such a way that they're hard to see, so I'd like to be able to control the color of these icons, but I can't figure out how.  I've tried using black icons and gray icons, but they appear the same in the tab bar.  Here are the source images:

[image: black house icon]
[image: gray house icon]

But these both appear exactly the same in the tab bar, namely, the same silver color as the tab bar itself, or blue, if the tab is selected.  (I'm showing the home icons here, but the same is true of the other icons.)

So how can I tint the tab bar but control the icon color?  And can you have full color icons in the tab bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change tint color of `UITabBarItem` icon, but you can set images to selected and unselected states:

```
[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"home-selected"]
              withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"home-unselected"];
```

Comment: That worked, thanks.  But why is there an Image property AND a FinishedImage property?

Comment: UIKit does not provide any automatic treatment to finished images.